# AmazonAdsAPIでメディアタイプ「application/vnd.spCampaign.v3+json」のコンテンツを渡す方法

Tags: c#, http

C#でAmazonAdsAPIでメディアタイプ「application/vnd.spCampaign.v3+json」のコンテンツを渡すにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

現在C#のHttpClientでADSAPIのsp/campaigns/listをpostで実行しようとしています。
こちらはメディアタイプ「application/vnd.spCampaign.v3+json」でコンテンツを渡す必要があります。
しかしながらこの形式でコンテンツを作成する方法が分かりません。

このメディアタイプでコンテンツを渡す方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

### 参考

Make your first call to the Amazon Ads API
https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/getting-started/first-call#/sample-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちら自己解決いたしました。
メディアタイプ「application/json」の時と同様にjson形式でStringContentを作成し、
メディアタイプを「application/vnd.spCampaign.v3+json」に変更して解決いたしました

```
public static async Task<StringContent> GetContentFormJson(object data, Encoding encode = null, Encoding contentEncoding = null)
{
    try
    {
        var json = dataをjsonに変換
        if (json != null)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(json, contentEncoding ?? Encoding.UTF8, @"application/json");
            content .Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.spCampaign.v3+json");
            return content;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        エラーログ処理
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `"application/json"`を指定してから`"application/vnd.spCampaign.v3+json"`に書き換えるのではなく、最初から`"application/vnd.spCampaign.v3+json"`を指定しておいた方がスマートかなと。